# Is it possible to redirect FTP requests to another IP using NGINX?

Tags: nginx, ftp, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two linux VMs with IPs `192.168.1.10` - VM1 and `192.168.1.11` - VM2. NGINX is running in VM1. VM2 is ftp server. I can successfully upload files to `192.168.1.11:21`.

What I am trying to achieve is, instead of using the IP of VM2, is it possible to use IP of VM1 to upload files using nginx?

### EDIT

I am looking for something like below;

```
upstream ftp_server {
    server 192.168.1.11:21 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an `upstream` directive?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to forward a TCP stream to another server.
So something like this should work for you:

```
stream {
    upstream backend {
        server 192.168.1.11:21;
    }

    server {
        listen 21;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```